# How to downcast in Unity C# when you need to access specific subclass information on hover?

Tags: c#, xml, inheritance, serialization, unity-game-engine

**EDIT 2**

This is what is being shown in the unity debugger when I look at the list of Items. It is seeing the baseball bat as an Item type, not WeaponItem type.

[image]

**EDIT 1**

This is currently all I have in my ItemsContainer ( my old file has the bloated xml file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ItemsContainer>
  <Items>
    <!--Weapon Items-->
       <WeaponItem Name = "Baseball Bat" ID="501">
          <!--General Info-->
          <Description>A wooden bat that may have belonged to somone famous</Description>
          <!--Weapon Item-->
          <Damage>4</Damage>
          <Targets>1</Targets>
       </WeaponItem>
   </Items>
</ItemsContainer>
```

**ORIGINAL POST**

*I'm working on a complex inventory system for a 2D game in Unity.*

I read game data with XML serialization and have set up a drag/drop system that works using an Item class. I've also gotten pretty far with a dialogue system that can tell what items are in certain characters inventories.

> **Issue:**
>
> Want to be able to downcast to an item subclass in order to access
>   specific data about it on a UI hover (*At least that's what I think I
>   need to do*), *or find another solution on how to setup my item database*

For eg:

- When you hover over a WeaponItem - it shows you damage information + desc
- When you hover over a general Item - it only shows you desc

**History:**

What I have right now is a very bloated Items.xml file that has all tags necessary, regardless of item category. This is really painful to maintain as I come up with new Items and categories - so I wanted to try **inheritance**.

At first, my initial approach was:

```
<ItemsContainer>
   <Items>
      <Item>
          <!-- Generic tags or attributes: ID, Name, Description etc -->
          <!-- Other tags that define the item, is there in every item!-->
      </Item>
   </Items>
</ItemsContainer>
```

and now it's this:

```
<ItemsContainer>
   <Items>
      <WeaponItem>
          <!-- Generic tags or attributes: ID, Name, Description etc -->
          <!-- WeaponItem specific tags: Damage, Targets Etc -->
      </WeaponItem>
      <ClothingItem>
          <!-- Generic tags or attributes: ID, Name, Description etc -->
          <!-- ClothingItem specific tags: Exposure, ArmorRating Etc -->
      </ClothingItem>
      .
      . 
      .
   </Items>
</ItemsContainer>
```

My Item class looks like this:

```
public class Item 
{
   [XmlAttribute("Name")]
   public string Name;
   [XmlAttribute("ID")]
   public int ID;
   // General Info
   public string Description;
   public virtual string GetDetails()
   {
      return
        "\nName: " + Name +
        "\nID: " + ID +
        "\nDescription: " + Description;
   }
}
```

While my subclass WeaponItem looks like this:

```
class WeaponItem : Item
{
   public int Damage;
   public int Targets;
   public override string GetDetails()
   {
       return
           base.ToString() +
        "\nDamage: " + Damage +
        "\nTargets: " + Targets;
   }
}
```

Here's what my ItemsContainer looks like:

```
[XmlRoot("ItemsContainer")]
public class ItemsContainer
{
    [XmlArray("Items"),XmlArrayItem("WeaponItem"), XmlArrayItem("ClothingItem"),...]
    public List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();

    public static ItemsContainer Load(string path)
    {
       TextAsset _xml = Resources.Load<TextAsset>(path);
       XmlSerializer Serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ItemsContainer));
       StringReader reader = new StringReader(_xml.text);
       ItemsContainer items = Serializer.Deserialize(reader) as ItemsContainer;
       reader.Close();
       return items;
    }
}
```

My ItemUI class contains:

- Item variable
- Several public game objects (I have a prefab of the game object this
  class is attached to)
- OnDrag, EndDrag, BeginDrag methods

What I want to do in ItemUI - is sort of something like this:

```
public void HoverOn()
{
    if(Item.Class == "Weapon")
    { 
        WeaponItem WeaponItem = (WeaponItem) Item; // Downcast Fail
        Damage.txt = WeaponItem.GetDamage() + "";
        Damage.gameObject.SetVisible(true);
    }
    else if(Item.Class = "Clothing")
    {
        ClothingItem ClothingItem = (ClothingItem) Item; // Downcast Fail
        Exposure.txt = ClothingItem.GetExposure() + "";
        Exposure.gameObject.SetVisible(true);
    }
    ItemInfo.gameObject.SetVisible(true);
}
```

> **Question:**
>
> With the fact that I want my items in separate categories in XML, how would I accomplish showing Item information based on the subclass of the Item, if all I have at the time of access is a higher level Item class type?

Comment: It sounds like it's not the cast that's the problem - it's how you're loading the items to start with. Have you looked in your list to see what the *actual* type of the objects being created is?

Comment: @JonSkeet When I call a ToString() on it, I get Item.

Comment: Well I was suggesting looking in the debugger rather than just using `ToString()`, but it certainly *sounds* like it's not deserializing to the specific types...

Comment: @JonSkeet I've added an image - you're right, it's getting the type Item - not WeaponItem, would that mean that something is up with my xml setup?

Comment: Yes. You could try using `XmlArrayItem("WeaponItem", Type=typeof(WeaponItem))` etc - but I don't know enough about XML serialization to know if that would work. I'd experiment with this outside Unity btw, just because it'll be a simpler environment to prototype in.

Comment: @JonSkeet It is now reading as a WeaponItem! It shows BASE and WeaponItem specific information. I'm going to experiment as you suggested and will implement my hover again to see if it works fully.

Comment: Okay - let me know if it works, and I'll add that as an answer...

Comment: @JonSkeet Definitely :D

Comment: @JonSkeet Please add your suggestion as an answer. I got my hover displaying separate info for each category. Thankyou!

Comment: Glad it worked out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't the cast - it's the XML deserialization. The serializer is only creating `Item` instances, which is why the cast is failing.

You need to change your attributes to tell the serializer which types you want to create:

```
[XmlArray("Items")]
[XmlArrayItem("WeaponItem", Type = typeof(WeaponItem))]
[XmlArrayItem("ClothingItem", Type = typeof(ClothingItem))]
[...]
public List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();
```

Note that rather than a series of `if` statements, you might also want to just switch on `Item.Class`. (And in C# 7, you'll be able to use pattern matching to switch on the type instead...)

Comment: Wish I could grant extra pts for the switch idea!

Answer (score 1):

You can check the type of the item with the `is` operator and do the rest as you planned.

```
if (Item is WeaponItem)
...
```

Another way of course would be to create a method or property for UI description and override it in to classes. This way you don't need to recode anything in the UI if you add new types.

Comment: I still wouldn't know how I would access specific attributes in WeaponItem, like Weaponitem.GetExposure(), because it's still seeing the Item from a highlevel and I can't do a downcast.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! The solution was actually something in my XML, but the "is" keyword definitely organized my checks.